# Update XML in SQL Server 2005 w/out Node causes Null Error

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, sqlxml

So i have a script to update/Insert the XML value of the following Node to True:

```
<Submitted>False</Submitted>
```

The issue is not all rows will contain the  Node and because of this, it throws the error: "Mutator 'modify()' on '@temp' cannot be called on a null value."

What do i need to do to filter out the rows which do not contain the "Submitted" Node within the XML?

**Note, i have all these crazy CASTS because the column type is TEXT and cannot be changed because the client originally set it up that way.

```
DECLARE @temp XML

SELECT 
     @temp = CAST(CAST(TicorOregon..tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items.XML AS NTEXT) AS XML) 
FROM 
     TicorOregon..tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items
WHERE
 CAST(CAST(TicorOregon..tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items.XML AS NTEXT) AS XML).value('(//Record/Submitted)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') <> 'True'

-- modification to local XML var
SET 
   @temp.modify('replace value of (//Record/Submitted[1]/text())[1] with "True"') 

-- write it back into the table as TEXT column      
UPDATE 
   TicorOregon..tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items
SET 
   XML = CAST(CAST(@temp AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS TEXT)
WHERE
 CAST(CAST(TicorOregon..tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items.XML AS NTEXT) AS XML).value('(//Record/Submitted)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') <> 'True'
AND  CAST(CAST(TicorOregon..tbl_Module_RequestForms_Items.XML AS NTEXT) AS XML).value('(//Record/Submitted)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') <> null
```

Comment: Thanks. It's the best i could do with this damn column being TEXT and the data XML with no way of changing the column type thanks to the customer who set this up.

Comment: Think i need to add an IF EXISTS statement, working on this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test your XML variable for null before trying to update.

```
if @temp is not null
begin
  -- modification to local XML var
  SET @temp.modify ----

  -- write it back into the table as TEXT column
  SET @temp.modify....
end
```

Note: You might have trouble with this code if there are more than one row having `<Submitted>False</Submitted>`. You will have the XML from one row in `@temp` (probably the last one according to some index) but you will update **all** rows where `<Submitted>False</Submitted>` with that XML.

Comment: just what i needed. YOU ARE DA MAN!

Comment: Can you please me with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974700/why-do-i-receive-a-mutator-error-when-modifying-an-xml-value-in-sql