# Why do I receive a Mutator error when modifying an Xml value in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ektron

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpPro]
(
    @PN varchar(200),
    @xml xml,
    @gVa varchar(10),
)
AS
/* update the gender */
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select @gVa = t1.[Gender] 
    From [myDb].[dbo].[myTable1] t1 --replace Value2 and table to the table which is updated through SSIS
    Where t1.Name = @PN

    PRINT @gVa //displays 'F'

    Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/Phys/gender/text())[1] with sql:variable("@gVa")');
END

/* once all the node has been "temporarily" changed, update the table columns for the provider */
BEGIN
    --update the table after casting dummy xml variable
    Update [myDb].[dbo].[TC]
    Set [chtml] = cast(cast(@xml as nvarchar(max)) as ntext)
    Where [ctitle] = @PN
END
```

When I run the query, I get the following error:

> Msg 5302, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpPro, Line 115
>   Mutator 'modify()' on '@xml' cannot be called on a null value.

How can I resolve the error. I am trying to update xml value in a column (`chtml`) which is of type `ntext` in the `TC` table.

Please let me know if I have to provide more information.

Just to test out the code, I just tried the following and it still gave the same error:

```
DECLARE @gVa varchar(10)
DECLARE @xml xml

Select @gVa = t1.[Gender] 
From [myDb].[dbo].[myTable1] t1 --replace Value2 and table to the table which is updated through SSIS
Where t1.Name = 'Doctor 1'
PRINT @gVa

If @xml IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/Phys/gender/text())[1] with sql:variable("@gVa")');
END
Else
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NOT WORK'
END
```

Keeps printing `NOT WORK`

Original column (`chtml`) data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Phys>
        <gender>M</gender>
    </Phys>
</root>
```

After the above SP executes, the `gender` should be `F` and not `M`

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) And if your data is XML - why aren't you use the `XML` datatype to store it? It's more efficient than a "simple" `varchar` or even worse: `ntext`

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the response. It is a CMS which is still using `ntext` unfortunately, hence why I am casting it at the end. My modify statement should work correctly, because there is a value there and not a null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error actually says it all, `@XML` is null and that is not allowed.

Repro:

```
declare @X xml;

set @X.modify('replace value of text()[1] with "1"');
```

> Msg 5302, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Mutator 'modify()' on '@X' cannot
>   be called on a null value.

Check for null before you modfy.

```
declare @X xml;

if @X is not null
  set @X.modify('replace value of text()[1] with "1"');
```

Comment: I have more `@X.modify()` in the stored procedure and this was the first one. Do I have to check each time or just the first time? That worked by the way. Thank you.

Comment: Actually nevermind, it didn't work. I don't get the error anymore but it never executes the `.modify()` statement. I updated my question.

Comment: When the stored procedure first executes, `@xml` is always null because there is nothing in it yet. I just realized, you helped me in my last question I had about this. :)

Comment: @SiKni8 I don't get it. Why do you have a parameter if it is always null?

Comment: I wanted to use a global variable which I can use inside multiple `BEGIN` and `END` statement. If I send you partial code can you show me where the error is? It WAS working, not sure why it isn't now.

Comment: Global variable? No such thing in SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry I meant use a variable that can be used through out the stored procedure.

Comment: @SiKni8 you need to assign the value in the column to the variable before you modify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91514/discussion-between-sikni8-and-mikael-eriksson).

Comment: No need to use a parameter for that. Local variable is there in the entire procedure.

Comment: I invited you to a chat. I did assign `@xml` at the beginning of my SP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977044/how-to-replace-xml-variable-through-sql